# Flattening lists inside a Pandas series

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a list:

```
[[ambulance],[],[]]
[[truck],[bus],[],[company],[ambulance]]
[[bus],[],[],[]]
```

And I'm trying to clean this to:

```
[ambulance]
[truck,bus,company,ambulance]
[bus]
```

I tried `list.explode()` but still have the empty `[]` and where there's 2 items it's index in duplicated like:

```
1 [truck]
1 [bus]
1 []
1 [company]
1 [ambulance]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `explode`, use `.str[0]` to get the first value of each sub-list or NaN if there is none, then `dropna`, and reconstruct the lists with `groupby(level=0)` + `agg(list)`:

```
df['l'] = df['l'].explode().str[0].dropna().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                  l
0                       [ambulance]
1  [truck, bus, company, ambulance]
2                             [bus]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just `map` `sum`

```
df['l'] = df['l'].map(lambda x : sum(x,[]))
```